# Bootstrap Accordion not working in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am trying to develop Accordion and I am following https://codepen.io/rugor/pen/hwyzn. I have created Angular 5 app using angular cli. After that in installed bootstrap and Jquery through npm. I copied same code from codepen. Below is my angular.json file which contains links to bootstrap and jquery.

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "JsonTree": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/JsonTree",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "scripts": [
               "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
               "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"

            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "JsonTree:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "JsonTree:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "JsonTree:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "JsonTree-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "JsonTree:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "JsonTree:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "JsonTree"
}
```

Whenever I run the code, everything appears as plain text as shown in below image. May I know what is the reason to not applying bootstrap styles? Can someone help me on this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
[image: Accordian]

Comment: you did not imported bootstrap into the project

Comment: Hi, I have added   "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
               "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
               "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" in the angular,json file

Comment: are you getting any console error?

Comment: Yes Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in script.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the bootstrap css file in your angular.json config

Try adding the `styles` attribute at the level of the scripts attribute:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```

Comment: thanks. where should i add that file? I can see styles tag in two places. one inside test and one inside projects

Comment: It should be under projects, just as you have done the js files :)